# When box height *vh row inside box is too long and dont work with min-height/height

Tags: html, css

im trying to fix when my div with class box-const-height but it gets super long but i can't make it just the height of the elements inside.

```
.box-const-height {
    display: flex;
    height: 80vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

<div class="row box box-const-height">
     <div class="row" style="min-height:auto;">
           <div class="col form-group">
           </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYmdS.png)